# Can I merge two data frames by partial string match of a common column?

Tags: r, string, dplyr, merge, fuzzy-search

I have two data frames that I wish to merge into one based on the column "Species"

## Dataframe 1:

| Species |
| --- |
| Themeda australis |
| Themeda avenacea |
| Themeda quadrivalvis |
| Themeda triandra |
| Lomandra juncea |
| Lomandra longifolia |

## Dataframe 2:

| Species | Common_name |
| --- | --- |
| Themeda australis (R.Br.) Stapf | Kangaroo grass |
| Themeda avenacea (F.Muell.) Lugger | Native oat |
| Themeda quadrivalvis (L.) Kuntze. | Grader grass |
| Themeda triandra Forssk. | Kangaroo grass |
| Lomandra juncea (F.Muell.) Ewart | Desert Mat-rush |
| Lomandra longifolia Labill. | Spiny-headed Mat-rush |

```
df1 <- data.frame(Species =  c(
  "Themeda australis",
  "Themeda avenacea",
  "Themeda quadrivalvis",
  "Themeda triandra",
  "Lomandra juncea",
  "Lomandra longifolia"
))
df2 <- data.frame(Species = c(
  "Themeda australis (R.Br.) Stapf",
  "Themeda avenacea (F.Muell.) Lugger",
  "Themeda quadrivalvis (L.) Kuntze.",
  "Themeda triandra Forssk.",
  "Lomandra juncea (F.Muell.) Ewart",
  "Lomandra longifolia Labill."
), Common_name = c(
  "Kangaroo grass",
  "Native oat",
  "Grader grass",
  "Kangaroo grass",
  "Desert Mat-rush",
  "Spiny-headed Mat-rush"
))
```

However, because there are multiple species containing the same string, I would like to match the data frames by only the **first two words** of column Species (e.g. Themeda triandra == Themeda triandra Forssk.). Keeping in mind that I am working with big data: Dataframe 1 is 32,931 rows and Dataframe 2 is 16,185 rows. No matches can be denoted NA.

## Desired output:

| Species | Common_name |
| --- | --- |
| Themeda australis | Kangaroo grass |
| Themeda avenacea | Native oat |
| Themeda quadrivalvis | Grader grass |
| Themeda triandra | Kangaroo grass |
| Lomandra juncea | Desert Mat-rush |
| Lomandra longifolia | Spiny-headed Mat-rush |

Is this possible?

I have tried the following:

```
output <- df1 %>%
  fuzzy_inner_join(df2, by = "Species", match_fun = str_detect)
```

Comment: Would it suffice to reduce df2$Species to the first two words? `df1 %>% left_join(df2 %>% mutate(Species = stringr::word(Species, end = 2)))`

Comment: There’s a package for fuzzy join. Have you searched?

Comment: @IRTFM did you see the bit in the answer with `fuzzy_inner_join()`?

Comment: I suggest - especially if you have to do such lookups more often - to **once** process your lookup table (df2) and add the simplified name and store that. Then each time you want to process df1 and get the common name (or even the full name) you can do just a normal join.

Comment: @Mark. Yes I did see that. What I did not see was any mention of a particular package or evidence of searching for prior questions that might have consider similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 %>% mutate(Species = str_extract(Species, "^([\\w\\-]+) ([\\w\\-]+)"))
```

Result:

```
               Species           Common_name
1    Themeda australis        Kangaroo grass
2     Themeda avenacea            Native oat
3 Themeda quadrivalvis          Grader grass
4     Themeda triandra        Kangaroo grass
5      Lomandra juncea       Desert Mat-rush
6  Lomandra longifolia Spiny-headed Mat-rush
```

Actually it seems there is no need for join. We can just extract the first two words from `Species` column. Anyway You can (simple, not fuzzy) join this resulting data.frame with any other data.frame having two-word Species column.

Comment: I added the dataframes to the question, so I removed them from your answer. It is now a one-liner! :-) edit: two liner

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing things, if asd-tm's answer doesn't work for your larger dataset:

Instead of extracting the names based on the structure of the Species names in the second dataframe, I look for a match for any string in the Species column of the first dataframe (`|` means match any of them)

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 |> mutate(Species_clean = str_extract(Species, paste(df1$Species, collapse = "|")))
```

Output:

```
                             Species           Common_name        Species_clean
1    Themeda australis (R.Br.) Stapf        Kangaroo grass    Themeda australis
2 Themeda avenacea (F.Muell.) Lugger            Native oat     Themeda avenacea
3  Themeda quadrivalvis (L.) Kuntze.          Grader grass Themeda quadrivalvis
4           Themeda triandra Forssk.        Kangaroo grass     Themeda triandra
5   Lomandra juncea (F.Muell.) Ewart       Desert Mat-rush      Lomandra juncea
6        Lomandra longifolia Labill. Spiny-headed Mat-rush  Lomandra longifolia
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the sample data is a bit confusing, where it looks that we can just get the result straight from df2 without taking df1 into account as it gives the same result.

However, OP clearly mentions differently *"Dataframe 1 is 32,931 rows and Dataframe 2 is 16,185 rows. No matches can be denoted NA."*

I suggest to alter once df2 (your lookup table). Not sure where you read that data from but perhaps write the lookup table with this extra column so you do not have to redo this task every lookup.

```
df2 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(Species_short = gsub("(\\w+ \\w+).+", "\\1", Species))
```

After that, just left_join it with your df1

```
df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("Species" = "Species_short"))
```

**Results**

```
#                               Species                         Species.y           Common_name
# 1                    Themeda triandra          Themeda triandra Forssk.        Kangaroo grass
# 2                   Themeda australis   Themeda australis (R.Br.) Stapf        Kangaroo grass
# 3                Themeda quadrivalvis Themeda quadrivalvis (L.) Kuntze.          Grader grass
# 4 Funky species without a common name                              <NA>                  <NA>
# 5                    Themeda triandra          Themeda triandra Forssk.        Kangaroo grass
# 6                     Lomandra juncea  Lomandra juncea (F.Muell.) Ewart       Desert Mat-rush
# 7                 Lomandra longifolia       Lomandra longifolia Labill. Spiny-headed Mat-rush
# 8                    Themeda triandra          Themeda triandra Forssk.        Kangaroo grass
# 9                     Lomandra juncea  Lomandra juncea (F.Muell.) Ewart       Desert Mat-rush
```

**Data df1** *(changed from OP)*

```
df1 <- data.frame(Species =  c(
  "Themeda triandra",
  "Themeda australis",
  "Themeda quadrivalvis",
  "Funky species missing in df2",
  "Themeda triandra",
  "Lomandra juncea",
  "Lomandra longifolia",
  "Themeda triandra",
  "Lomandra juncea"
))
```